# Fade effect on display="block" action in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, css-transitions

I have some javascript that is switching between 3 divs on click of 1 of 3 tabs.

Here is my Javascript:

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.acidTabs = function(options) {     
            var settings = {
                        'style' : 'one'
             };     
                options = $.extend( settings, options );
                return this.each (function () {     
                    var o = options;
                    container = this;
                    container.setAttribute("class",o.style);
                    var navitem = container.querySelector("li");
                    //store which tab we are on
                    var ident = navitem.id.split("_")[1];
                    navitem.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",ident);
                    //set current tab with class of activetabheader
                    navitem.setAttribute("class","tabActiveHeader");

                    //hide two tab contents we don't need
                    var pages = container.querySelectorAll(".tabpage");
                    for (var i = 1; i < pages.length; i++) {
                        pages[i].style.display="none";
                    }

                    //this adds click event to tabs
                    var tabs = container.querySelectorAll("li");
                    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                        tabs[i].onclick=displayPage;
                    }
                });

                // on click of one of tabs
                    function displayPage() {
                        var current = this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-current");
                        //remove class of activetabheader and hide old contents
                        document.getElementById("tabHeader_" + current).removeAttribute("class");
                        document.getElementById("tabpage_" + current).style.display="none";

                        var ident = this.id.split("_")[1];
                        //add class of activetabheader to new active tab and show contents
                        this.setAttribute("class","tabActiveHeader");
                        document.getElementById("tabpage_" + ident).style.display="block";
                        this.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",ident);
                    }
            };
})(jQuery);
```

I cant seem to modifiy this to accept fading effects. Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Would love your help!
Thank you.

Comment: For jQuery this complex, I would recommend creating a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net); it really helps people answer your question.

Comment: I just need something I can use with .style.display="block" to create a fade in effect. dont need a fade out.

Comment: Anyone???? Please help. Seems so easy

Comment: As @Ethan said, create a fiddle showing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it's not easy because you can't do it. 
You need to split the two css statements.

New div with opacity:0 and display:none
change display to block
and then change opacity using setTimeout (even a 10ms delay will do).

do the opposite for the div that will hidden.

something like this:

```
var newdiv=document.getElementById("tabpage_" + ident);
newdiv.style.display="block";
setTimeout(function(){newdiv.style.opacity="1";},10);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out with some help from the asp.net forum. Replace the function displayPage() with this:

```
var current = this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-current");
//remove class of activetabheader and hide old contents
$('#tabHeader_' + current).removeClass('tabActiveHeader');
$('#tabpage_' + current).hide();

var ident = this.id.split("_")[1];
//add class of activetabheader to new active tab and show contents
$(this).addClass("tabActiveHeader");
$('#tabpage_' + ident).fadeIn();
this.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",ident);
```